# Smallest $k$ such that if $z= x + iy$ , then $|x| + |y| \leq k|z|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

If $z= x + iy$, then $|x| + |y| \leq k|z|$, where the smallest possible value of $k$ is?

Options:

$a) \ 1$

$b)\  \sqrt 2$

$c)\ \sqrt3$

$d)$ None of the above.

---

By using geometry, I can see that if $|x|$ is equal to $|y|$, then $|z|$ will become equal to $\sqrt2|x|$ (or $\sqrt 2|y|$). But, I would like a mathematical proof for the same which I am unable to arrive at. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to math SE! Here is a mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, it is unclear what the question is. Are we supposed to find $k$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. The value of 'k' is asked in the question.

Comment: Yikes... You undid all the MathJaxing.  I'm rolling back that undo and putting the correct wording in.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry. I still need to learn MathJax, I think.

Comment: I still find the wording of this question strange. If I'm not mistaken (b) is the 'actual' answer? There is no reason why option (c) isn't valid either if that is the case.

Comment: I get your point Shuri2060. But, I think that the questions asks the minimum permissible value of k.

Comment: @Shuri2060 has a point.  Is the goal to find the *smallest* value of $k$ that works?

Comment: Sounds like it.

Comment: Look at it this way. Of all right triangles with a hypotenuse of 1, what is the greatest possible perimeter?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting $z$ in polar form, let $z = |z| \cos \theta + i|z|\sin\theta$.

If $z$ is in the first quadrant, $0 \le \theta \le \frac\pi2$, then

$$\begin{align*}
|x| + |y| &= x + y\\
&= |z| \cos\theta + |z|\sin\theta\\
&= \sqrt2 |z| \cos\left(\theta - \frac\pi4\right)\\
&\le \sqrt 2|z|
\end{align*}$$

Equality holds when $\theta = \frac\pi4$, i.e. $x = y$.

The result is similar if $z$ is in other quadrants, but where $|x|$ may equal to $-x$ instead, or $|y|$ may equal to $-y$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted if  $|x|=|y|=1$ then $|z|=\sqrt{2}$ and 
$$2=|x| + |y| \leq k|z|=k\sqrt{2}\implies k\geq \sqrt{2}.$$
In order to show that the smallest constant $k$ such that the  inequality $|x| + |y| \leq k|z|$ holds is $\sqrt{2}$, it suffices to prove that
$$(|x|+|y|)^2\leq 2|z|^2=2(x^2+y^2),$$
which is true because 
$$2(x^2+y^2)-(|x|+|y|)^2=|x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2=(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x $ and $y$ are real.

Let $Z=x +iy =re^{i\theta}=r(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})$
$$|x|+|y|=r(|\cos{\theta}|+\sin{\theta}|)$$
$$(|x|+|y|)^2=r^2(1+|\sin{2\theta}|)$$
Now use $|\sin{x}|\le 1$